# Как правильно переписать if через тернарный оператор

Tags: c#

```
if(Amount <= 0)
   throw new Exception ("exception")
else 
   this.Amount = Amount;
```

Comment: Выражения тернарного оператора должны возвращать значения одинакового типа. [Статья на MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: зачем это переписывать и в чем смысл выражения `this.Amount = Amount;` ? Вы переменные как поля называете?

Comment: @tym32167, а почему бы и не называть переменные как поля? :)

Comment: А зачем вообще менять понятный if, на не факт что понятный тернарный оператор?

Comment: Собственно ключевое слово else ты и сейчас можешь убрать и ничего не поменяется.

Comment: @Grundy чтобы не путаться конечно, даже гайдлайны от МС так не рекомендуют делать, если я верно помню.

Comment: Смысл в том, что я в конструкторе проверяю на правильность вводимых данных

Comment: ну так используйте контракты или напишите свой служебный класс для этих проверок

Answer (score 2):

```
this.Amount = Amount > 0 ? Amount : throw new Exception("Exception");
```